# Accessibility by Layer not by Assembly

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a business layer object that travels across layers, Widget. I want it to expose a different set of properties in different layers. Here's how it would look if compilers read comments:

```
//bl.dll

public abstract class Widget
{
    //repo only
    internal virtual Ppty_A {get;set;} //internal to implementation assembly of repo

    //repo and service only
    internal virtual Ppty_B {get;set;} //internal to implementation assemblies of repo/svc

    //everyone inlcuding presentation
    public virtual Ppty_C {get;set;} 
}
public interface IWidgetService
{ ... }    }
public interface IWidgetRepo
{ ... }
public class SimpleWidgetService : IWidgetService
{ ... }

//dal.dll
using bl;
public WidgetRepo
{ ... }

//presentation.dll
using bl;
public WidgetController
{
    public WidgetController(IWidgetService ...)
    ...
}
```

My idea is to do this (I haven't tested this yet and it solves only half the problem):

```
//bl.dll
public abstract class Widget
{
    //repo only simply can't be defined in the abstraction -- can't see you => no contract

    //repo and service only has to be public?
    public virtual Ppty_B {get;set;}

    //at least public is public...
    public virtual Ppty_C {get;set;} 
}

//dal.dll
using bl;
public SQLWidget : Widget //Or actually DALBLWidget -- see below?
{ 
    //repo only
    internal ...
    internal ...

    //the rest
    ...
}
```

Should I just create another abstract Widget (have a DAL-BL Widget and a BL-UI Widget)?

Comment: Why do you want this design? Wouldn't it be a better idea to have custom made DTO's for each layer and only pass the data that is required?

Comment: I'm not aware of a good option to painlessly update the whole "column" when I have to make changes; my intuition is to minimize the number of types representing the same entity (I was hoping to only need one more, for the ORM)

Comment: What do you mean by updating the whole column?

Comment: @WouterdeKort, I don't want to manually change the ORM configuration, dto, ... , dto, viewmodel whenever I change something.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the Widget class implement different interfaces that correspond to each layer.

```
public class Widget : IDataLayerWidget, IBusinessLayerWidget
{
 // Properties
}

public interface IDataLayerWidget
{
   // Properties visible to the DataLayer
}

public interface IBusinessLayerWidget
{
   // Properties visible to the BusinessLayer
}
```

In your DataLayer you would work with the `IDataLayerWidget` and in your business layer with the `IBusinessLayerWidget`.

Comment: Not something I considered, but what I want is isolation. At the moment, I don't see how this would prevent the Presentation layer from working with `(IDataLayerWidget)Widget` or `(IBusinessLayerWidget)Widget`.

Comment: It doesn't. If you don't want a layer to access the data of another don't give that layer access to the data.
There is no perfect solution to your problem. Either have separate Widgets for every layer and do the mapping. That gives you separation. Or share your data objects across all layers and live with the high coupling.

Comment: @SebastianWeber, your "yes" answer is what I'm having to live with. I'd gladly "accept it" here as well.